Import formula from variable - Excel VBA
Using the below code i m trying to loop column and rows. When cells in green import the range in the formula string. At row 7 i want to import a formula which sum up the green cells but i want the formula to be shown. the loop works fine, the formula create fine but is imported as string instead of a formula.
Any help will appreciated.

Sub test()

    Dim Row As Long
    Dim Col As Long
    Dim strFormula As String
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Loop columns
        For Col = 1 To 3
            'Clear strFormula variable
            strFormula = ""
            'Loop rows
            For Row = 1 To 5
                'Check if cell is green
                If .Cells(Row, Col).Interior.Color = 9359529 Then
                    'Create formula
                    If strFormula = "" Then
                        strFormula = """=SUM(.cells(" & Row & "," & Col & ")"
                    Else
                        strFormula = strFormula & ",.cells(" & Row & "," & Col & ")"
                    End If
                Else
                End If
                
            Next Row
            
            'Finalize formula
            If strFormula <> "" Then
                strFormula = strFormula & ")"""
                'Import formula
                .Cells(7, Col).Formula = strFormula
            Else
            End If
            
        Next Col
    
    End With
        
End Sub


Remove the triple quotes (""") at the start and end of your formula and just use a single quote instead (")

I get the same result, thus i have import them.

Please do not name your variable as Row. Row is a property and this will interfere with that.
I would do this slightly different. I would identify the range which has the relevant color and construct a range object which will have only those cells. In the end I will use it with an apostrophe ' to enter the formula as text.
Is this what you are trying?
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim cl As Long
    Dim rngGreen As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    With ws
        For cl = 1 To 3
            Set rngGreen = Nothing
            
            For rw = 1 To 5
                If .Cells(rw, cl).Interior.Color = 9359529 Then
                    If rngGreen Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngGreen = .Cells(rw, cl)
                    Else
                        Set rngGreen = Union(.Cells(rw, cl), rngGreen)
                    End If
                End If
            Next rw
            
            If Not rngGreen Is Nothing Then .Cells(7, cl).Formula = _
            "'=Sum(" & rngGreen.Address & ")"
        Next cl
    End With
End Sub

Note: To get the sum, you can use "=Sum(" & rngGreen.Address & ")" without the apostrophe.


I have another quetions for you. Lest say i want ot import a formula in D7 which subtract A7 from C7. How i will write the formula in terms of .cells(rw,cl)

Many ways to do it. Here is one. .cells(rw,4).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-3]"

is there a way with .Formual function?

You mean like this .Cells(rw, cl).Formula = "=C" & rw & "-A" & rw

hi again. I m using "=Sum(" & rngGreen.Address & ")" to import the formual into a cell. Is there a way to pass the result of the formula to a variable?

Oh yes. Ret = .Evaluate("=Sum(" & rngGreen.Address & ")")

I have notices that rngGreen in after additing many cells it 's starts overriding the existing cells in the with the new onces. Is there any way to overcome this?

Sorry I did not understand. What do you mean?

it seems that rngGreen has limit number of characters. As I union the cells, at a certain point it start's to overwrite previous cells from the rngGreen

Can I see an example of what yo umean?

Sum Up Highlighted Cells Using Formula

Sub SumupHighlightedCells()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        
        Dim urg As Range, cell As Range, r As Long, c As Long
        Dim Formula As String, IsCellFound As Boolean
        
        For c = 1 To 3
            ' Combine green cells in current column into unioned range.
            For r = 1 To 5
                Set cell = .Cells(r, c)
                If cell.Interior.Color = 9359529 Then ' is green cell
                    If IsCellFound Then
                        Set urg = Union(urg, cell)
                    Else
                        Set urg = cell
                        IsCellFound = True
                    End If
                'Else ' is not green cell
                End If
            Next r
            ' Check if green cells found in current column.
            If IsCellFound Then ' green cell(s) found
                ' Write formula.
                Formula = "=SUM(" & urg.Address(0, 0) & ")"
                .Cells(7, c).Formula = Formula
                ' Reset for the next iteration.
                IsCellFound = False
            'Else ' no green cells found
            End If
        Next c
    
    End With
        
End Sub


It is not the correct syntax for Excel formulas. You can use something like this:
Sub test()
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim Col As Long
    Dim strFormula As String
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) ' "Sheet1"
        'Loop columns
        For Col = 1 To 3 Step 2
            'Clear strFormula variable
            strFormula = ""
            'Loop rows
            For Row = 1 To 5
                'Check if cell is green
                If .Cells(Row, Col).Interior.Color = 9359529 Then
                    'Create formula
                    If strFormula = "" Then
                        strFormula = "=SUM(R" & Row & "C" & Col
                    Else
                        strFormula = strFormula & ",R" & Row & "C" & Col
                    End If
                End If
            Next Row
            
            'Finalize formula
            If strFormula <> "" Then
                strFormula = strFormula & ")"
                'Import formula
                .Cells(7, Col).FormulaR1C1 = strFormula
            Else
            End If
        Next Col
    End With
End Sub

